# Join two table mysql but i dont know what type

Tags: mysql

I am new to databases. I know some relation like : left join, right join etc

But I don't know what exactly I need to get output that I expected, so here are my two tables:

**Transaction** table

```
transaction_id | date       | amount | user_id
---------------+------------+--------+----------
      1        | 2018-08-18 |   100  | 1
      2        | 2018-08-18 |   100  | 1
      3        | 2018-08-19 |   100  | 2
```

**User** table

```
user_id | name  | email           | password
--------+-------+-----------------+-----------
   1    | alice | alice@email.com | xxx
   2    | smith | smith@email.com | xxx
```

So the transaction table store about transaction that user did.

I want to output like this :

```
date       | SUM(amount) | user_id
-----------+-------------+---------
2018-08-18 |     200     | 1
2018-08-18 |       0     | 2
2018-08-19 |       0     | 1
2018-08-19 |     100     | 2
```

This is the query I tried:

```
select 
    transaction.date, 
    sum(transaction.amount), 
    user.user_id 
from 
    transaction 
left join 
    user on user.user_id = transaction.user_id 
group by 
    date, user.user_id
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want 0 results for each day you have grouped for every user even if there were no transactions performed by this user...? I'm sorry but... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date,
(
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(transaction.amount), 0)
  FROM transaction
  WHERE
    transaction.user_id = user_ids.user_id
  AND
    OuterTable.date = transaction.date
) as amount,
user_ids.user_id
FROM transaction OuterTable,
     (SELECT user_id FROM user) user_ids
GROUP By date, user_ids.user_id
```

You can check it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29ee67/9

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know the sum of the transactions for each day for each user, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT 
    t.date,
    sum(t.amount) as amount,
    t.user_id
FROM 
    transactions t
GROUP BY
    t.date, t.user_id
```

You don't need to perform a join since you have this information already in this table, unless you wanted to output the name of the user or other information from him.

As of, outputing 0 as sum for users without transactions for that specific date, consider this: if you have 100 users, you would have 100 rows for each day. In a month that's 3000 rows. And for every user, another row created. This can grow exponentially. So **thread** carefully there. :)

Comment: ,i need every date to make some chart all of user